# Why's this break in IE10/11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, responsive-design, alignment

I'm racking my brain.

http://www.coflash.com/wendy/

In IE, for some reason, the last tile in IE goes out of alignment. It works fine in iOS/Chrome/Firefox.

I tried compressing the HTML to remove all spaces, I recalculated the percentages, I just don't get it. Hopefully someone here will.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of the percentage widths on the `li` elements, the max width on the `img` element, the border-box box-sizing on the `img` element and the calculation of the maintenance of the aspect ratio between width and height of the images, means that IE is computing the height of the double width images to 249.98px and the single width images to 249.91px.

As each image is floated, IE is taking in to account that 0.07px difference to determine that for the first out-of-position image, the column 3 position is available slightly higher up the page that the column 1 position, so it puts the image there.

Simplest solution is to set the height of the images to 250px, instead of auto.